# How can I make a dropdown menu from just an icon with ant design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to make a user icon with a dropdown menu using ant design libraries and reactjs.  If I use Dropdown.Button, I'm getting a box around the icon. I think this is related to a CSS border-box property, but I can't seem to get rid of it.  If I use the Dropdown component, then I can't add an icon and can use only text.  What's the right way to achieve this result?

```
import { Menu, Dropdown } from 'antd';
import { UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const Dummy = () => {
  const userMenu = (
    <Menu>
      <Menu.Item key="1">Item 1</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="2">Item 2</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="3">Item 3</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Divider />
      <Menu.Item key="3">Logout</Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown.Button
        style={{ float: 'right' }}
        overlay={userMenu}
        icon={
          <UserOutlined
            style={{
              fontSize: '28px',
              backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
              borderRadius: '50%',
            }}
          />
        }
      ></Dropdown.Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dummy;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired styling via CSS.

Add a `className=dropdown-btn` to the `Dropdown.Button` component

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Menu, Dropdown } from 'antd';
import { DownOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Menu, Dropdown } from 'antd';
import { UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const Dummy = () => {
  const userMenu = (
    <Menu>
      <Menu.Item key="1">Item 1</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="2">Item 2</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="3">Item 3</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Divider />
      <Menu.Item key="3">Logout</Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown.Button
        style={{ float: 'right' }}
        className="dropdown-btn"
        overlay={userMenu}
        icon={
          <UserOutlined
            style={{
              fontSize: '28px',
              backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
              borderRadius: '50%',
            }}
          />
        }
      ></Dropdown.Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dummy;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Dummy/>,
  document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

Add CSS to target the offending border and background-color:

```css
.dropdown-btn > .ant-dropdown-trigger  {
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-btn > .ant-dropdown-trigger > span {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

If the use of `!important` is a problem, you can add more selectors to increase the specificity.

Working StackBlitz link:
https://ant-design-dropdown-link-button.stackblitz.io

P.S. Another quick and dirty solution is to add the `type="link"` attribute to the `Dropdown.Button`. This will get rid of the border styling, but the background color will remain and the icon will turn blue.

Comment: This doesn't hide the option '...' that appear next to the Dropdown.Button due to the overlay parameter

Comment: Why don't you just use Popover
 `<Popover placement="bottomRight" title={'titl'} content={userMenu} trigger="click">
      // do whatever you want here ...
      // E.g: <UserOutlined />
   </Popover>`
[antd popover](https://ant.design/components/popover/)